# Reporject the image to 3D using opencv3

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I'm trying to use cv2.reprojectImageTo3D function to get (x,y,z) coordinates. 
but it gives me negatives values of z.
can i convert this coordinates to real distance?
can i calculate the depth from it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this line of code:

```
_points = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disp, q).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Where disp is the disparity map of your depth image. And q is the repojection matrix.

If you want  to know the relationship between the 3D coordinates and their actual distance to camera, you need a constant factor that tells the relationship. You should have it already from the camera calibration part.

Comment: Thanks for replaying, i'm using this function i get the q matrix after calibration:           (left_rectification, right_rectification,left_projection, right_projection,q, left_ROI, right_ROI) = cv2.stereoRectify(M1, d1,M2, d2, self.img_shape, R,None,None,None,None, None,cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY)
Where can i find the constant factor ??

Comment: Hi, you can go to this wiki page to find out how it works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection